# Javascript Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I am getting a missing ) after argument list in the chrome console. I don't understand why because it doesn't seem like there's missing one. I know it's not because of the string I'm passing because the string actually show how it's supposed to. so here's my code :

This is the HTML code:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="button" onclick="annuler(@ViewBag.id_dcr,@ViewBag.number)">
        Annuler 
</button>
```

This is the Javascript function :

```
function annuler(id_dcr, number) 
{
    window.location.href = ("/ModifyDocument/Index?id_dcr=" + id_dcr + "&number=" + number);
}
```

This is the C# method that pass the informations :

```
public ActionResult Create(int? id_dcr, int? id_user, string number)
{
    ViewBag.Documents = dbd.documents.Where(i => i.number == number).ToList();
    ViewBag.id_dcr = id_dcr;
    ViewBag.number = number;
    return View();
}
```

This is the C# method definition that'll be call in the JavaScript function:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id_dcr, string number)
```

Comment: In `annuler(@ViewBag.id_dcr,@ViewBag.number)` if the values are string, they need to be wrapped in quotes.

Comment: what happen if you just put hard-coded values (e.g : onclick="annuler('id', 3);" ?

Comment: Look at the *rendered output* and check what’s wrong there.

Answer (score 1):

This should fix it:

```
   <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="button" onclick="annuler('@ViewBag.id_dcr','@ViewBag.number')">
            Annuler 
    </button>
```

Comment: `ViewBag.number` is a string, so it could technically contain a `'` character, or even worse, a `"` character (leading to invalid markup).